# How to Filter on multiple strings in JS?

Tags: javascript, filter, ecmascript-6, include, filtering

I want to be able to filter on multiple strings(types) in an array. For example I want to filter on type **meat** and type **fruit** in the data-structure below. 
What I want to achieve is a filtered data object.

```
const data = [{type: "meat", food: "hamburger"}, {type:"fruit", food:"banana"}, {type:"fish", food: "red snapper"}, {type:"vegetables", food:"fungi"}]

let filter1 = 'meat'
let filter2 = 'fruit'

const filteredData = data.filter( post => post.type.includes(filter1, filter2) ? post:'');

// My expected result after filtering: [{type: "meat", food: "hamburger"}, {type:"fruit", food:"banana"}]
```

Unfortunately it returns 4 results instead of the 2 as expected above.

I know how to deal with this in libraries like _underscore.js but I want to achieve it in modern EcmaScript.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create an array of the `type`s you want to include first, and *then* you can use an `.includes` test on that array. (Currently, your `post.type.includes(filter1, filter2)` doesn't work because `includes` only accepts one argument)

```js
const data = [{type: "meat", food: "hamburger"}, {type:"fruit", food:"banana"}, {type:"fish", food: "red snapper"}, {type:"vegetables", food:"fungi"}]

let filter1 = 'meat'
let filter2 = 'fruit'

const filters = [filter1, filter2];

const filteredData = data.filter(({ type }) => filters.includes(type));
console.log(filteredData);
```

You could also use a `Set` for less runtime complexity

```js
const data = [{type: "meat", food: "hamburger"}, {type:"fruit", food:"banana"}, {type:"fish", food: "red snapper"}, {type:"vegetables", food:"fungi"}]

let filter1 = 'meat'
let filter2 = 'fruit'

const filters = new Set([filter1, filter2]);

const filteredData = data.filter(({ type }) => filters.has(type));
console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: Thank you for these clear examples. Helped me a lot to understand this concept better. I have one more question; How to achieve this approach if you want to filter if each type consist of two instances, like type: {type: ["meat", "american"], food: hamburger}?

Comment: That'll be somewhat more complicated, iterate over the `entries` of the filter object and check if `some` of the values match (if array), or if the plain value matches (if string)

Comment: @CertainPerformance what if the strings inside 'filters' are in capital letters and we want to change them to lowerCase() first before matching with the 'type' in filter ?

Comment: @bubble-cord Change `new Set([filter1, filter2]);` to `new Set([filter1, filter2].map(str => str.toLowerCase()));`

Comment: @CertainPerformance How to change/check for lowerCase()  inside the loop itself const filteredData = data.filter(({ type }) => filters.includes(type));
console.log(filteredData); ?

Comment: @bubble-cord You'll need to lower-case both collections. With the Set method - map to lower-case like the above comment, then call `toLowerCase` when filtering. `.filter(({ type }) => filters.has(type.toLowerCase()));`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Okay that worked but somehow, it is not taking care of the words with space. For example, my array of a string looks like this [' Sun Flower', 'Water Melon']. It only returns the correct result if I enter a complete exact string like 'Water Melon', not If I search for 'melon' or 'water' or just 'Water'. Can you help justify this reason & solution for the same?

Comment: @bubble-cord `Set#has` and `Array#includes` only find exact matches, they don't search for substrings. If you want to find a substring, you'll need another inner loop, something like `str => filers.some(filter => filter.includes(str.toLowerCase()))`