# Cant remove vowels from an array using filter that has multiple conditional statements

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, palindrome, splice

```
wordArr = ['a', 'g', 'e', 'f'];
wordArr = wordArr.filter(function(l){
            return l !== 'a' || l!== 'e'|| l!== 'i'|| l!== 'o' || l!== 'u'; 
       });
```

My result: my wordArr doesnt change

Desire output: ['g', f'];

it only works with one condition, if i only check for one vowel. How do i make this work for multiple conditions?

thank you in advanced.

Comment: Related: [Javascript filter check for multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37807845/8289918) [How to Filter on multiple strings in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52909487/8289918) [how to filter multiple values from an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68100851/8289918) It's almost the same as your situation except you would use e.g. `!invalid.includes(l)` instead of `invalid.includes(l)` for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your conditions are incorrect. Consider just the following:

```
return l !== 'a' || l!== 'e'
```

If the string (inside `l`) is `foo`, the result is `true` since it's not `'a'`.

If the string is `'a'`, the result is `true` since it's not `'e'`:

```
return l !== 'a' || l!== 'e'
return false || true
return true
```

If the string is `'e'`, the result is `true` since it's not `'a'`:

```
return l !== 'a' || l!== 'e'
return true || false
return true
```

You need `&&`s instead.

```
return l !== 'a' && l!== 'e'&& l!== 'i'&& l!== 'o' && l!== 'u';
```

Or, even better:

```js
const wordArr = ['a', 'g', 'e', 'f'];
console.log(wordArr.filter(str => !/[aeiou]/.test(str)));
```

Comment: I'd be interested to see what's faster; `RegExp.prototype.test()` or `Set.prototype.has()`

Comment: wow thank you for such an in depth response and explanation! I see where my logic went wrong after this thank you! just starting to learn programming so this has been really helpful

Comment: If you want to filter out uppercase vowels as well with the regex, you could use `/[aeiou]/i`

Answer (score 2):

You are using `||` here which will check for either of the condition that causing the problem. Just use `&&` instead of `||`

```js
wordArr = ["a", "g", "e", "f"];
const result = wordArr.filter(function(l) {
  return l !== "a" && l !== "e" && l !== "i" && l !== "o" && l !== "u";
});

console.log(result);
```

Alternatively, you can use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check for existence.

```js
const wordArr = ["a", "g", "e", "f"];
const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"];

const result = wordArr.filter((l) => !vowels.includes(l));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You might want to include the uppercase variants in your `vowels` array

Comment: Thanks for providing multiple solutions to my issues, this was extremely helpful!